# TCP Client not receiving responses back from RTSP server

Tags: delphi, sockets, delphi-xe2, rtsp, tcp

In Delphi XE2, I'm using the `TTCPClient` component to communicate with an RTSP server. After trial and error not getting a response back from the server, I switched the project to send HTTP requests via port 80 (instead of 554 for RTSP) and tried to send a request to a website (www.google.com specifically). I'm still not getting any response.

I have a `TTCPClient` component on the main form (`Form1`) called `Client`, a `TMemo` control called `Log`, a `TEdit` control called `txtHost`, and a `TBitBtn` control. Here's the relevant parts of the code:

**Connecting to Server**

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Client.Active then Client.Disconnect;
  Client.RemoteHost:= txtHost.Text;
  Client.RemotePort:= '80'; // '554';
  Client.Connect;
end;
```

**OnConnect Event Handler (HTTP)**

```
procedure TForm1.ClientConnect(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: String;
begin
  Client.Sendln('GET / HTTP/1.0');
  Client.SendLn('');
end;
```

**OnConnect Event Handler (RTSP)**

```
procedure TForm1.ClientConnect(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: String;
begin
  Client.SendLn('OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0');
  Client.SendLn('CSeq:0');
  Client.SendLn('');
end;
```

**OnReceive Event Handler**

```
procedure TForm1.ClientReceive(Sender: TObject; Buf: PAnsiChar;
  var DataLen: Integer);
var
  S, R: String;
begin
  S:= Client.Receiveln;
  while S <> '' do begin
    R:= R+ S;
    S:= Client.Receiveln;
  end;
  Log.Lines.Append('> RECEIVED ' + R);
end;
```

**OnError Event Handler**

```
procedure TForm1.ClientError(Sender: TObject; SocketError: Integer);
begin
  Log.Lines.Append('> ERROR '+IntToStr(SocketError));
end;
```

The `OnReceive` event is never called, nothing is coming back from any Server I'm connecting to.

What am I doing wrong here?

**References**

These are some links which I'm referencing to:

- http://effbot.org/zone/socket-intro.htm
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt
- http://folk.uio.no/meccano/reflector/smallclient.html
- http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/reference/rtsp_specification.html

The camera I'm working with is `Grandstream GXV3601LL`

**UPDATE**

I've concluded that the issue is with the RTSP server, and have asked a question on the forums on Grandstream's website. The code does work with other server connections.

Comment: Actually, it worked for HTTP, but not yet for RTSP...

Comment: May I ask why are you using the ages old TTCPClient? Indy is easier to work with...

Comment: I'm just throwing a sample together to make sure I have the general communication concept down before I start the real project here.

Comment: So it seems as if I will have to pass this question on to the camera's vendor, since it does work properly with RTSP feeds such as Youtube.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me, it depends if you are in blocking mode or not:

```
unit Unit11;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Sockets, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
    TcpClient1: TTcpClient;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure TcpClient1Connect(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TcpClient1Receive(Sender: TObject; Buf: PAnsiChar; var DataLen: Integer);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TcpClient1.BlockMode := bmBlocking;
 TcpClient1.RemoteHost := 'www.google.com';
 TcpClient1.RemotePort := '80';
 TcpClient1.Connect;
end;

procedure TForm1.TcpClient1Connect(Sender: TObject);

var s : string;

begin
 memo1.Lines.Add('connected');
 TcpClient1.Sendln('GET /');
 s := TcpClient1.Receiveln;
 memo1.Lines.Add(S);
end;

end.
```

**EDIT**

here is a real world example with a RTSP server (youtube in this case)
I used Indy IdTcpClient

```
unit Unit11;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Sockets, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Client: TIdTCPClient;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

var s : string;

begin
 Client.Host := 'v5.cache6.c.youtube.com';
 Client.Port := 554;
 Client.Connect;
 Client.IOHandler.Writeln('OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0');
 Client.IOHandler.Writeln('CSeq: 1');
 Client.IOHandler.Writeln('');

 s := Client.IOHandler.ReadLn;
 Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
 s := Client.IOHandler.ReadLn;
 Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Hmm, it does work for me using your example, but when I put the IP of the RTSP camera it fails with socket error 10053

Comment: error 10053 is WSAECONNABORTED, so it seems that the camera is not allowing your connection. What brand of camera are we talking about here?

Comment: I've also verified all the camera's settings, including one to allow anonymous unauthenticated viewing

Comment: it should be doable, you just need to include an authorization element. Look at this page for pointers :http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=44780

Comment: I guess I'll have to accept your answer since it does really answer the question, yet I still have an issue of these particular cameras not responding. I've posted a question in Grandstream's forums on this.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `OnReceive` event is not called is because `TTCPClient` is **NOT** an asynchronous component, like you are trying to treat it.  The `OnReceive` event **DOES NOT** work the same way as the old `TClientSocket.OnRead` event.  The `OnReceive` event is called inside of the `ReceiveBuf()` method only (`ReceiveLn()` calls `ReceiveBuf()` internally).  The data that is passed to the `OnReceive` event is the same data that the `ReceiveBuf()` method returns on output.  You have a catch-22 situation - you are waiting for the `OnReceive` event before calling `ReceiveLn()`, but `OnReceive` will not be triggered until you call `ReceiveLn()` first.  If you want to use `TTCPClient` asynchronously, you will have to call its `ReceiveLn()` method periodically, either in a timer or worker thread, **NOT** inside the `OnReceive` event.

The `TTCPClient` component is part of the old CLX framework for Kylix.  It is not part of the VCL, or even FireMonkey, and should not be used anymore.  Either use the old `TClientSocket` component (which is deprecated but still available), or change to another component library, such as Indy.